# Getting Node error while implementing elastic search with NEST in C#

Tags: asp.net, api, elasticsearch, nest

I am getting this error while implementing Elastic API in my project.
**No nodes were attempted, this can happen when a node predicate does not match any nodes.**
Has Anyone had any knowledge regarding this error?

Comment: This can happen if you define a predicate that will not match any nodes that the client knows about, when determining a node to run a request against. Take a look at the documentation at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/sniffing-role-detection.html#_node_predicates

Comment: @RussCam I provided my answer below w/ the caveat that I cannot explain why I would see that condition sporadically in a single node or single load balancer scenario.  Any thoughts why this exception would occur sporadically in that scenario?

Answer (score 2):

One scenario I can add here is where [your cluster contains only a single node or you are interacting with your cluster through a single load balancer instance.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connection-pooling.html#single-node-connection-pool)  I discovered that a `SniffingConnectionPool` may sporadically throw this exception (ie. **No nodes were attempted**).  I cannot explain why this only happens sporadically but I solved it by using a `SingleNodeConnectionPool` as Martijn Laarman explains [here.](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-net-sniffingconnectionpool-requires-open-transport-port/75727/4)  The scenario in that link is another similar case to mine (ie. Elastic Cloud).

Comment: This is still true in 2021. Switching to SingleNodeConnectionPool for single cloud installations fixed the issue.